# Was Ruby On Rails affected by CVE-2019-16201?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cve

I didn't find a short answer to my question,[CVE-2019-16201](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2019-16201/) was a vulnerability on WEBrick on Ruby, was RubyOnRails affected by this vulnerability as well?

I say yes because I found RubyOnRails used WEBrick as mentionned [Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server#:%7E:text=The%20Ruby%20standard%20library%20comes,a%20default%20development%20web%20server.).

I say no because on [CVE-2019-16201](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2019-16201/) I don't find any reference to it about RubyOnRails, and I believe that this vulnerability was crucial and must have been mentioned here.

I hope the answer is yes, because I have to reproduce this vulnerability in an environment, and it would be easier to do so, I believe, using ruby on rails.

Thanks to all of you.

Comment: This answer is enough for me! thanks, you may want to post it down ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please note:** That this is not a rails vulnerability but rather a vulnerability in the [WEBrick library](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/v3_0_0/tool/lib) that ships with ruby (rails is not a requirement to use this library)

So if your rails application is:

- using WEBrick as its HTTP server; and
- running on one of the [affected versions](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/10/01/webrick-regexp-digestauth-dos-cve-2019-16201/); and
- using digest authentication provided by WEBrick

Then I would say yes the rails application is vulnerable.